# If a function has $k+1$ roots on an interval, then its $k$th derivative has a root there

Tags: calculus, derivatives, numerical-methods

Suppose that $$a  \le x_0 < x_1 < ... < x_k  \le b,$$ $$f(x_0) = f(x_1) = ...= f(x_k) = 0,$$ and $$f(x), f'(x),...,f^k(x),$$ are all continuous on $[a,b]$. Show that there is a  $\delta \in (x_0,x_k) \subset (a,b)$
such that $f^k(\delta)= \ 0.$

How to do this? Do I have to use Taylor's expansion?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use  *Rolle's theorem* multiple times, and induction on $k$.

Comment: Thank you. I was applying the wrong theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Rolle's theorem repeatedly. Under your stated hypotheses, there are (at least) $k$ points $x$ where $f'(x) = 0$. Thus there are (at least) $k-1$ points $x$ where $f''(x) = 0$, and so on.

Comment: Thank you. I was applying the wrong theorem.